# Symfony 3: How to create a private bundle

Tags: unit-testing, repository, composer-php, bundle, symfony

I have a private API and I am using GuzzleHttp bundle to make calls to it. Now I'm just creating a sub-folder in the `src/MyCompany/ApiBundle/..` and I register it in the AppKernel.php and use it without errors.

Now I need to make this a separate bundle (in its own private repository) so I can use it inside different projects.. I followed many tutorials but always face problems as they are for Symfony 2.

Symfony has a tutorial ([Generating a New Bundle Skeleton](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html)) on the docs but it doesn't talk about external bundles like in my case.

**So how to create such bundle?** be able to test it and make it in its own repository to be later integrated inside other projects using composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundle should be separate project. Check some [fos bundles](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony)

Also check [Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)

You may also like to check

- [Using private repositories with composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories)
- [Handling private packages with Satis or Toran Proxy](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md)